# x86 assembly functions

Tags: function, assembly, x86-64

I have a function that is called by main. Assume that function's name is `funct1`. `funct1` calls another function named `read_input`.

Now assume that `funct1` starts as follows:

```
push %rbp
push %rbx
sub $0x28, %rsp
mov $rsp, %rsi
callq 4014f0 read_input
cmpl $0x0, (%rsp)
jne (some terminating function)
```

So just a few of questions:

1. In this case, does `read_input` only have one argument, which is
   `%rbx`?
2. Furthermore, if the stack pointer is being decreased by
       `0x28`, this means a string of size `0x28` is getting pushed onto the
       stack? (I know it's a string).
3. And what is the significance of
   `mov %rsp, %rsi` before calling a function?
4. And lastly, when `read_input` returns, where is the return value put?

Thank you and sorry for the questions but I am just starting to learn x86!

Comment: Where does your code come from? Did you generate it from C source?

Comment: Decreasing the stack pointer could mean that local variables are allocated on the stack.

Comment: To 4: maybe the return value is on the stack because the top of the stack is compared with 0 in the instruction following the call to read_input.

Comment: @Giorgio yes generated from C source using objdump -d.

Comment: @Giorgio I only have access to the `main` function of the C code and the rest is hidden from me. I am not supposed to see it.

Comment: @Giorgio - NO.  The return values for both AMD/Linux and Windows x64 ABIs are in `rax` (or maybe a floating point register). *NOT* on the stack.  The check in this code is checking to see if `read_input` filled in the passed-in buffer with only a null character (ie, an empty string).

Comment: What compiler are you using? ASAIK the register where the result of an operation is saved is normally on the left on x86 assemblers, whereas in 'sub $0x28, %rsp' the register is on the right.

Comment: @Giorgio - the OP's code is in normal AT&T assembly syntax.

Comment: @Carl Norum: OK. actually I would have expected that too (I mean, that the return value is in rax if it fits in a register).

Comment: @Carl Norum: OK, that means that the stack pointer is saved in rsi after the subtraction.

Comment: @Giorgio - correct.  `rsi` is a parameter passing register, so it makes sense to stick a copy of the address of the new buffer in there, so that `read_input` can fill it in.

Comment: @Carl Norum: I know that the stack pointer is often saved in rbp after pushing rbp. Do you have any idea why this is not the case here?

Comment: @Giorgio - sometimes code is compiled to optimize out the frame pointer.  It can make stack unrolling harder, but it's pretty much 100% optional.

Comment: @Carl Norum: OK, so the buffer is allocated with sub $0x28, %rsp, and then the address is saved in rsi. This must also be an optimization because normally you could just push the address onto the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your code is using the Linux/AMD ABI.  I'll answer your questions in that context.

1. No, `rbx` is a callee-saved (nonvolatile) register.  Your function is saving it so that it doesn't disturb the caller's value.  It's not being restored in the code you've shown, but that's because you haven't shown the whole function. If there's *more* to this function, and I think there is, it's because `rbx` is being used somewhere later on in this routine.
2. Yes, space for 0x28 bytes of data is being made on the stack.  Assuming `read_input` is taking a string as a parameter, your description is reasonable.  It's not necessarily accurate, however.  Some of that data might be used for other local variables aside from just the buffer being allocated to pass to `read_input`.
3. This instruction is putting a pointer to the newly allocated stack buffer into `rsi`.  `rsi` is the second parameter register for the AMD x64 calling convention.  That means you're going to be calling `read_input` with whatever the first parameter passed to *this* function is, along with a pointer to your new stack buffer.
4. In `rax`, if it's a 64-bit value or smaller, in `rax` & `rdx` if it's larger.  Or if it's floating point, in `xmm0`, `ymm0`, or `st(0)`.  You probably should look at a description of your calling convention to get a handle on this stuff - there's a great PDF file at [this link](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).  Check out Table 4.